# Merge custom product attributes options in one

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I have many product custom attributes all have same type dropdown for **brand** like

```
brand_cosmetic
cos_acc_brand
face_brand
mobile_brand
```

They have lot of options. i want to make a new attribute name `product_brand` and want to merge all above attribute options in it is there any way in magento to do this programmatically. I have searched alot but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue its not the best way but it fixed my issue may be it helps someone as well so what i have done i made a **function** that is fetching all the options of brand attributes in my project

```
public function mergeAttributeOtionsAction(){
    $brands = array();
    $attSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_code','catalog_product')->getFirstItem(); // This is because the you adding the attribute to catalog_products entity ( there is different entities in magento ex : catalog_category, order,invoice... etc ) 
    $attSetCollection = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->load($attSet->getId())->getAttributeSetCollection(); // this is the attribute sets associated with this entity 
  foreach ($attSetCollection as $a)
    {
        if(preg_match('/cosmetic/i', $a->getAttributeSetName())){
            $set = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($a->getId());
            $setId = $set->getId();
            $atrr_ = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($setId);
            foreach($atrr_ as $atrr){

                $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$atrr['code']);
                if(preg_match('/brand/i', $attribute->getFrontendLabel())){
                    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
                    foreach ($options as $option){
                        if($option['label'] == 'Not Specified'){
                            continue;
                        }
                        $brands[] = $option['label'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>'; var_dump(implode(',', $brands));echo '</pre>';
    foreach ($brands as $brand){
        echo $brand; echo '<br>';
    }    

 }
```

the next step is to make an excel file in this format
[image]

than goto **admin > system > import/export > DataFlow - Advanced Profiles** Add new Profile enter name like "Import Product Attributes" and add this XML and save

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
<var name="type">file</var>
<var name="path">datafiles/import</var>
<var name="filename"><![CDATA[import_product_attributes.csv]]></var>
<var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
<var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[;]]></var>
<var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
<var name="fieldnames">true</var>
<var name="store"><![CDATA[0]]></var>
<var name="number_of_records">1</var>
<var name="adapter">importexportattributes/convert_adapter_product_attribute</var>
</action>
```

Now create a folder on magento root folder name datafiles inside this folder create another >import than place that XML file here that you have created above.

Now goto **admin > system > import/export > DataFlow - Advanced Profiles open "Import Product Attributes"** than click on **Run Profile** tab and click on **run profile** button. 
That's it now you have new attribute with name and code that you have enter in your file with all brands options that exists in magento.